# Adding foreign key to existing MySQL table via command line

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, foreign-keys

I am trying to add a foreign key to a table i've created in the terminal.

I've tried

```
ALTER TABLE table_name FOREIGN KEY key_name REFERENCES table_name1(key_name);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FOREIGN KEY key_name REFERENCES table_name1(key_name);
```

but keep getting the same error message that tells me my syntax is wrong.

Most of the questions related to this, though helpful, they don't talk about how to add a foreign key in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html), looks like you're just missing parentheses

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FOREIGN KEY (key_name) REFERENCES table_name1(key_name);
-- ....................................^........^
```